# Python: Disabling [X] button in console

Tags: python, cmd, console

How to *disable* [**X**] button?
But **not** in **thinker or other GUI's modules**, I want do it in ***console***.
Example:

```
while True:
     a = input('Enter close command: ') 
     if a == 'stop':
          exit()
```

Do **NOT** show me example with **GUI** module.

Comment: You want to disable closing of a terminal window? I don't think you can do that... or would ever really, *really* want to do that. You might be able to run your program in the background as a service instead.

Comment: There is way to make console in Thinker or PyQt5?
@Tenacious B